# Known alternative to DMX512 & RDM

Tags: communication, protocol, lightning

Hi does anybody know of any other lighting communication protocol other than DMX512 and RDM?

I'm currently evaluating protocols and would not want to miss potential candidates.

Thank you.

Comment: you have actually googled 'lighting communication protocols' I assume because I'm surprised you've only come up with two.

Comment: haha, yes of course. That is how i ended with dmx and RDM. Simply trying to get some inputs from experience users.

Comment: God did invent Google for a reason. But then, he also invented stack exchange.

Comment: There's [DALI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Addressable_Lighting_Interface). The company I work for also has 2 or 3 custom in-house protocols used in different product lines.

Comment: [BACnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BACnet) is also used for lighting. It can run over IP networks too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is ACN, specifically S-ACN which was supposed to replace DMX but is kind of complicated.

Then there is Art-Net which is something Artistic License came up with that basically encapsulated DMX in UDP, popular because it is simple (Unlike ACN!) and lets you stuff a lot of DMX down a ethernet link (512 channels starts looking a bit thin when pixel mapping a big display).

That plus DMX deals with the current common ones in entertainment lighting, there are about a dozen other more of less historical ones (PMX, D54, Martin were seen in the UK, and I think Colourtran had something in the US market, then there were the two 0->10V standards (Strand used 0-> -10V, everyone else 0 -> +10V), one wire per channel.

Outside the entertainment game there are some commonly used for architectural work: DALI and DSI, plus some propitiatory ones common in offices and the like.